# Get a dll version number from database at compile time

Tags: c#, batch-file, compilation

I need to retrieve a number version from database to add this as dll version.

I can add manually this version each time I publish, but I'll like to run this in an automatic process.
So, is it possible at compile time to execute a SQL or any operation to get this number ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It ought to be a lot easier to update the dbase from the version number, that way it is simple, all in one place and the odds that somebody forgets to increment it a lot lower :)

Comment: Obviously, this is the easiest and logical way. But on the project where i'm affected, the version is given by package's team and not by developper's team :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a small simple application (command line) that looks up the version or build number and replaces it in the appropriate file.

Then you could add it as a pre-build event to your Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 1):

```
is it possible at compile time to execute a SQL or any operation 
to get this number
```

No you cannot call SQL at compile time. Compiling is purely for creating MSIL (dll or exe) to be executed later by the CLR. All work is performed by the JIT compiler of the CLR (which is at runtime). No work can be done at compile time.

However, you could add a pre build event (that would happen before the compilation), which gets data and writes it into a config file. The app can read the version number from here.
[image]

Comment: Unless you have a [pre-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2s2128d.aspx) to create a config file that the compiler uses.